# im2single vs. single - difference?

Tags: matlab, image-processing, matrix, floating-point

What is the difference between `im2single` and `single` in MATLAB when applied to a grayscale image?

I am doing some image processing work and found that changing a call `single(image)` to `im2single(image)` tripled my performance and I am now very curious as to the difference.

The MATLAB documentation for [single](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/single.html) and [im2single](https://www.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/im2single.html?s_tid=srchtitle) doesn't seem helpful on this point.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Similar to `im2double`, `im2single` will actually normalize all of your image data such that all values are between `0` and `1`. This scaling is necessary to get proper behavior when saving the image to a file or displaying it using `imshow`.

On the other hand, `single` will simply convert the image data to the `single` datatype with no scaling.

### Benchmark

You stated that `im2single` was faster than `single. This is very unlikely given the information above. I have designed a benchmark to test the two for images of different sizes.

```
function benchit()

    N = round(linspace(1, 10000, 20));

    times1 = zeros(size(N));
    times2 = zeros(size(N));

    for k = 1:numel(N)
        im = rand(N(k));
        times1(k) = timeit(@()im2single(im));
        im = rand(N(k));
        times2(k) = timeit(@()single(im));
    end

    figure
    p(1) = plot(N, times1, 'DisplayName', 'im2single');
    hold on
    p(2) = plot(N, times2, 'DisplayName', 'single');
    legend(p)

    xlabel('Image Size')
    ylabel('Execution Time (sec)')
end
```

[image]

Comment: If I'm using 8 bit images, would `im2single` then be equivalent to something like `single(image)/255`?

Comment: @kalaracey Almost. It's actually the same as: `im = single(image) - min(image(:)); im = im ./ max(im(:));`. It uses the values themselves to scale the data rather than the data type. If you need to normalize using a certain method, I would recommend doing it manually instead.

Comment: @suever Very interesting! Do you also know, why the scaling might enhance the performance of OP's code?

Comment: @Max I suspect that the performance wasn't measured properly using `timeit`

Comment: @suever Can the difference in using `timeit` as opposed to `tic toc` be that large that you can get a factor 3? @kalaracey Would it be possible to post the code that you observed the performance improvement on? I would like to try the benchmark.

Comment: @Max yes particularly if the same data is operated on. The first test that's run would always be the slowest in that scenario

Comment: @suever allright, thank you very much! Seems like you were right in the first place and it was just a mistake in time measurement.

Comment: I'm sorry, it seems there was some misunderstanding. By performance I was referring to the performance of my classification model, not it's speed. I never claimed `im2single` is faster than `single`.

Comment: @Suever `im2single` scales the data based on their type rather than the particular range of values. Please check the following examples:

`im2single(uint8(127)) --> 0.4980`
`im2single(int16(127)) --> 0.5019`
`im2single(uint16(127)) --> 0.0019`
`im2single(127) --> 127`